# NumericType Error - convert to a float for a calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df:
               a      b       c
date
2012-01-01   0.50    1.2    0.70 
2012-01-01   0.45    1.2    0.65
2012-01-01   0.65    1.2    0.63
2012-01-01   0.75    1.2    0.29
2012-01-01   -0.25   1.2    -0.68
```

I want to calculate:  a/b - c

I run:

```
new = df['a']/df['b'] - df['c']
```

This returns
    new:

```
date
2012-01-01   -0.2833 
2012-01-01   -0.2750
2012-01-01   -0.0883
2012-01-01   0.3350
2012-01-01   0.4717
```

First error:
If I go:

```
new.ix[0][0]
TypeError: 'NumericType' object is unsubscriptable
```

So I assume it's a series.

So I change it to:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(new)
type(new.ix[0][0])

<type 'NumericType'>
```

This is the weird part:

```
new.ix[0][0]
-0.2833
new.ix[0][0]/2
-0.141650
new.ix[0][0]/2.0
0
```

What is going on with the number type?  How can I change it to float?  What is the best practice here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the differences in behaviour is when `new` is a Series vs. a DataFrame.

The first `new` you create is a **Series**:

```
In [11]: s = new = df['a'] / df['b'] - df['c']

In [12]: type(s)
Out[12]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

This has a value in position `0` of `-0.2833`:

```
In [13]: s.ix[0]
Out[13]: -0.28333333333333327
```

*(You can't `__getitem__` on a float e.g. `2.0[0]` gives you a similar error.)*

However, when you then force it to a **DataFrame**:

```
In [14]: df_new = new = pd.DataFrame(s)

In [15]: df_new
Out[15]: 
          0
0 -0.283333
1 -0.275000
2 -0.088333
3  0.335000
4  0.471667

In [16]: type(df_new)
Out[16]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

this time the 0th index is a Series (row):

```
In [17]: df_new.ix[0]
Out[17]: 
0   -0.283333
Name: 0

In [18]: df_new.ix[0][0]
Out[18]: -0.28333333333333327
```

#### Update:

To ensure that all your DataFrames values are floats (`numpy.float64`) you can [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) (which works here since *every* column is being converted to a float):

```
df = df.applymap(float)
```

*I don't know how you got `NumericType` object, I assume the divide by 2 vs 2.0 derives from this.*

Comment: Thanks.  How come when I divide by 2.0 versus divide by 2 I get different answers?

My next step is to say - I want to divide: df_new/(1/df['b'])

  This gives me an error.

Comment: Beat me to it!  I need to refresh more often.

Comment: @user1911092 I don't see the behaviour with the 2 vs. 2.0 division. Could this be something strange with your set up  `numpy.float64`? (it is the *value* `x = new.ix[0][0]` which is demonstrating this behaviour? If so I think it is a separate issue...

Comment: @AndyHayden: I'm not even sure I've ever seen a `NumericType` object, come to think of it.

Comment: I thought it was from the calculation.  But if I apply(np.float64) it changes the numbers to what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: @DSM This 2 or 2.0 behaviour seems the opposite of what you might expect! Strange

Comment: Yeah, it's very weird.  I tried grepping through the `pandas` source going back a while but couldn't find any `NumericType` objects, and there are several possible candidates out in the Google wilds..

Comment: @user1911092 appended `df = df.applymap(float)` which will convert all values to floats (and you shouldn't see this `NumericType` issue).